# Symfony CMF Media Bundle - Could not load type "cmf_media_image"

Tags: image-uploading, symfony-cmf

I want to use the CMF Media Bundle for image uploads. The Bundle was installed successfully.

**routing.xml**

```
cmf_media_file:
    resource: "@CmfMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/file.xml"

cmf_media_image:
    resource: "@CmfMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/image.xml"
```

**AppKernel.php**

```
$bundles = array(
   ...
   new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\CmfMediaBundle(),
);
```

Now I want to add the following code to my **form**:

```
$builder    
-> add('image', 'cmf_media_image', array('required' => false))
;
```

But I get an **error message**:

> Could not load type "cmf_media_image"

What did i miss?

Comment: This form type only works with the phpcr storage. Did you enable phpcr either in CmfCoreBundle or on the CmfMediaBundle?

Comment: I tried to enable it: added thi following to config.xml --- cmf_media:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled: true --- but got an error using --- doctrine:phpcr:repository:init --- commant: "There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:phpcr:repository" namespace"

Comment: Then you are missing the <code>doctrine/phpcr-bundle</code> or do not instantiate it in your kernel. There is some documentation on the PHPCR bundle in http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/phpcr_odm/introduction.html

Comment: If you want to use ORM, you would need to look into the form type and see if you can adjust it to also work with Doctrine ORM. A pull request to make that possible would be great - ORM support for the form type is something we want but nobody had time to build it.

Comment: DId you solve this? I have same issue. Running `php app/console container:debug --tag=form.type | grep image` only shows the liip type. Very few google results for this. Followed all the instructions. Can see the fields.html.twig file in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should declare the template like this (in config.yml) :

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'CmfMediaBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/media/form_types.html for more info